# My web application is not working on IE10

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, internet-explorer-10

My web application which was working fine till now (on server), suddenly stopped working after IE is upgraded to IE10 version. It seems postback code is not at all getting called and hence nothing is happening.

I tried Hotfix as suggested in many place (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088) but it has no effect. 
Also i tried creating App_Browsers folder in my application and adding the browser definition files manually there but to no effect.

Same application is working fine in my development machine with IE 10 , but not on production server.

Guys please advice what could be wrong and why this hotfix has not worked for me.
Also what can i try to make this application working.

Regards,
Arpan

Comment: Check your Compatibility settings,

Comment: Can you post your website URL ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this  way's .

1: Update your server/website with the latest version of .net. The version you are using does not recognise the IE10 UAS.
to `debug your websites press f12>Script tab, click "Start Debugging"`

**SCRIPT5009: 'WebForm_GetElementByTagName' is undefined**

use Tools>Choose User Agent String and change the UAS to IE9 and the above error message disappears indicating that the version of .net you are using on your server is using UAS sniffing.

2: Upgrade your website  to .Net `4.0`. Then publish your website to the server and change the application pool to .Net `4`.

3: http://discusscode.blogspot.in/2012/12/fixing-aspnet-application-for-ie10.html

4: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, will try these things and get back.
Point 4, i have already tried and installed the machine level hotfix to no avail.